# No Cambia mi Matriz Matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

Estoy haciendo una division de una columa de una Matriz
Todo esa columna dato por dato lo divido entre otro dato (En específico que ya tengo)

todo bien hasta ahí si me hace mi division de mi Matriz

```html
>> MatH(posy,:)./(MatH(posy,posx))

ans =

   -1.0000    1.0000    0.5000         0    0.5000         0         0
```

pero al imprimir de nuevo mi Matriz
No  hace los cambios

```html
>> MatH

MatH =

     3     6     0     0     0     0     0
     0     3    -8     1     0     0     2
    -2     2     1     0     1     0     0
     1    -6     0     0     0     1    15
```

Que es lo que debería de hacer? para que los cambios que haga en una columna  se apliquen despues de que quiera imprimir mi Matriz

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tienes que indicarle a Matlab que guarde el resultado de la operación en la columna que te interesa. Es decir:

```
MatH(posy,:) = MatH(posy,:)./(MatH(posy,posx));
```